# Check if file from list exist or have the same basename

Tags: list, powershell, file-exists

I'm looking to optimize this script with a function

```
$Folder = 'K:\dxf\dxf50000-60000'
$filenames = Get-Content -Path .\files.txt
    
$missingFilesList = New-object System.Collections.ArrayList
Write-Host "Folder: $folder."
Write-Host "Searching for files"
    
foreach ($filename in $filenames) {
    $found=$false; 
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Recurse | ForEach-Object {if($filename -eq $_.BaseName) {Write-Host 'FILE ' $filename ' Ok' -foregroundcolor green; $found=$true;CONTINUE }$found=$false;} -END {if($found -ne $true){ Write-Host 'FILE ' $filename ' missing in the folder' -foregroundcolor red}}
}
```

Generally I'm looking for files with the same format everytime: basename-revision

51713-0 51762-0 51780-0

Now I also want to search for the basename (i.e 51713) and report this back with the basename and revision if found (and change the color to cyan or something) - what would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm confused - do these files not have extensions? Does `files.txt` contain just the basename, or both parts of the file name?

Comment: These files have extions indeed: DXF or step, but this is not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

My C:\files.txt contains the following content:

> 51713-0
> 51714-0
> 51714-1
> 51714-2
> 51714-3
> 51799-0

[Outputs the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5FBR.png)

```
# Define the folder where we look for the files
$FilesFolder = 'C:\dxf50000-60000'

# Define the list of files to check for
$FileNameList = Get-Content -Path c:\files.txt

# Get all the files in the FilesFolder
$ContainingFiles = Get-ChildItem $FilesFolder

Write-Host "Folder: $FilesFolder."
Write-Host "Searching for files"

# Go through each file in the FilesFodler
foreach ($FileName in $FileNameList) {

    # Define basename
    $BaseName = $FileName.Split("-")[0]

    # Define revision
    $Revision = $FileName.Split("-")[1]

    # If the folder contains a matching basename AND revision, write output GREEN
    If ($ContainingFiles.Name -like "*$BaseName-$Revision*"){

        Write-Host "Successfully found file basename [$BaseName] with revision [$Revision]" -ForegroundColor Green
            
    # If the folder contains a matching basename but NOT revision, write output CYAN
    }ElseIf ($ContainingFiles.Name -like "*$BaseName*"){

        Write-Host "Successfully found file basename [$BaseName] with revision [$Revision]" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    
    # If no matching basename was found, write output RED
    }Else{

        Write-Host "Failed to find file with basename [$BaseName]" -ForegroundColor Red
    
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks allot, this saves me allot of work checking all my files daily. Really appreciate the work and learning allot!